# Logstash, json array into single event with fields generated from element fields?

Tags: arrays, json, logstash

I am using http_poller as input and get back a json array. I'm using default json codec.
The json looks like this:

> [{"name":"UsedMemory","value":
>   {"value":"222932448","type":"java.lang.Long"}},
>   {"name":"FreeMemory","value":{"value":"308630048","type":"java.lang.Long"}},
>   {"name":"Heap","value":{"value":"531562496","type":"java.lang.Long"}},{"name":"UpTime","value":{"value":"29900897","type":"java.lang.Long"}},{"name":"ProcessCPU","value":{"value":"0.15846178794662266","type":"java.lang.Double"}},
>   {"name":"GcCount","value":{"value":"2198","type":"java.lang.Long"}},{"name":"GcTime","value":{"value":"35658","type":"java.lang.Long"}}]

I see that logstash treats each array element as a new event by splitting up the array.
Eg

```
{
    "name" => "UpTime",
    "value" => {
    "value" => "29579549",
    "type" => "java.lang.Long"
},
    "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-11-17T04:12:45.492Z"
}
{
    "name" => "ProcessCPU",
    "value" => {
    "value" => "0.16146030555740817",
    "type" => "java.lang.Double"
},
    "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-11-17T04:12:45.492Z"
}
...
```

How can I get logstash (2.4) to combine the elements, treat it as one event and output it like this

```
{
    "Uptime" => "29579549"
    "ProcessCPU" => ""0.16146030555740817"
    ....

}
```

I think I have to generate a new field like this but go through all the elements of the array to make one complete event.
{
"%{name}" => "%{[value][value]}"
...
}

Answer (score 1):

After reading a bit more about logstash and experimenting, I found the answer:

1. In the http_poller, change the codec to "plain"
2. In the filter section, use a json filter. eg

> ```
> json {
>   source => "message"
>   target => "doc"
>   }
> ```

3. Add a ruby code filter to process the json doc field as follows:

> ```
> ruby {
> code => "
> event['doc'].each { |elem|
> event[ elem['name']] = elem['value']['value']}
> "
> }
> ```

4. Remove doc and message fields using mutate filter